# How can I truncate the last 5 characters using CSS without ellipsis?

Tags: html, css

```js
const hide = document.getElementsByClassName("text-m");
const onlyNumbers = hide.replace(/\D/g, "");

console.log(onlyNumbers);
```

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-m" aria-label="15128 reviews" tabindex="-1">15128 Reviews</a>
```

I know I can use `text-overflow: " "` but I only want to truncate the last 5 characters and without ellipsis
How can I truncate non-numeric characters from a string?

This is my html

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="text-m" aria-label="15128 reviews" tabindex="-1">15128 Reviews</a>`
I tried to do this but it's not working. Where am I going wrong?

My JavaScript:

````
const hide = document.getElementsByClassName("text-m");
const onlyNumbers = hide.replace(/\D/g, "");

console.log(onlyNumbers);```
````

Comment: Hi please post the code you have tried to this question, otherwise it's harder to help you. Also read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: hide.replace is not a function. First question is why hide the ellipsis? It's the thing that shows the user a line is truncated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) will return a array-like object, you will have to grab the first item from that array, like this:

```js
const hide = document.getElementsByClassName("text-m")[0];
```

Also, `replace()` is not a method on html element, you need to grab the `textContent` from that `a` element.

```
const onlyNumbers = hide.textContent.replace(/\D/g, "");
```

Btw, I would advise you to use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) instead of `getElementsByClassName()`.